# swiftui clipped not cut image

Tags: uiimageview, swiftui

Hi I've a problem with image in SwiftUi, I've this layout:
[image: e]

The image and fitness are cliccable but when i click on fitness open the page of image.

This is my code:

```
VStack {
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        NavigationLink(destination: FullNewsListView(category: "Fitness")) {
            Text("Fitness")
                .foregroundColor(Color("#29B1B3"))
                .font(Font.custom("AvenirNextLTPro-Bold", size: 20))
            Image("forward_blue")
        }
        Spacer()
        }
    .padding(.bottom, 10)
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        HStack {
            URLImage(URL(string: "http://myPhoto")!) { proxy in
                proxy.image
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 180)
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                    .clipped()

            }

        }
        HStack {
            Text(api.newsFitnessHome.news!.title)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(Font.custom("AvenirNextLTPro-Demi", size: 15))
                .opacity(0.8)
                .lineSpacing(5)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
.padding(.horizontal, 30)
```

Comment: Is this in List?

Comment: no its not in list

Comment: I can see where you have the image, but I cannot see where you have the clickable image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cannot test because no all components available, but I suppose this is due to image hit area, see below some assumptions

```swift
URLImage(URL(string: "http://myPhoto")!) { proxy in
    proxy.image
        .renderingMode(.original)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 180)
        .cornerRadius(12)
        .clipped()
        .contentShape(Rectangle())      // try this
}
//.contentShape(Rectangle())      // or here
```

Comment: For me, applying `.contentShape(Rectangle())` to the **parent** of the `Image` worked. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, Asperi. I did notice that the order of modifiers matters.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this setup:

```
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                NavigationLink(destination: FullNewsListView(category: "Fitness")) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Fitness")
                            //   .foregroundColor(Color("#29B1B3"))
                            .font(Font.custom("AvenirNextLTPro-Bold", size: 20))
                        Image("forward_blue")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.bottom, 10)
        }

....
```

Also .foregroundColor(Color("#29B1B3")) does not work for me.

Comment: .foregroundColor(Color("#29B1B3"))  is my set color